# Why is 10^9942066 the biggest power I can calculate without overflows?

Tags: ruby, int, biginteger

In ruby, some large numbers are larger than infinity. Through binary search, I discovered:

```
(1.0/0) > 10**9942066.000000001 # => false
(1.0/0) > 10**9942066 # => true
RUBY_VERSION # => "2.3.0"
```

Why is this? What is special about 10<sup>9942066</sup>? It doesn't seem to be an arbitrary number like 9999999, it is not close to any power of two (it's approximately equivelent to 2<sup>33026828.36662442</sup>).

<del>Why isn't ruby's infinity infinite? How is 10<sup>9942066</sup> involved?</del>

---

I now realize, any number greater than 10<sup>9942066</sup> will overflow to infinity:

```
10**9942066.000000001 #=> Infinity
10**9942067 #=> Infinity
```

But that still leaves the question: **Why 10<sup>9942066</sup>?**

Comment: Ruby's infinity is clearly not infinite in the mathematical sense. It is by definition the largest number that it can handle.

Comment: There's no way of representing a true infinity in a numerical sense. Comparing things vs. "Infinity" is actually not really useful and `1/0` is undefined, not "Infinite" as Ruby would have you believe. If Ruby was mathematically correct then we could finally answer the question of "What is Infinity plus one?"

Comment: @sawa Clearly. However, it still leaves the question of where 9942066 came from.

Comment: How long did it take to evaluate that? My computer is hanging, calculating `10**9942066`.

Comment: @sawa Slightly longer than instantly. It didn't hang. Are you sure you're using version 2.3.0?

Comment: I can't reproduce it at all. Where does your Ruby come from?

Comment: @shelvacu It is probably buffer overflow. I shouldn't have tried to output the number. With your expression, it didn't take time.

Comment: @cremno Official arch linux repositories. Package version is `2.3.0-2`, 64 bit, md5 of the ruby binary is `f55d964b391e1bf987fc62e12de8497f` @sawa I'm able to output the number just fine (it takes ~10 seconds or so).

Comment: Also, `2**32537662` is infinity but `2**32537661` isn't.

Comment: My guess is that (no evidience!) since Ruby uses GMP to represent big integer internally, it may not pass a large enough buffer to GMP to host a number as large as you have shown. If you change the base to 2, maybe it's easier to see.

Comment: @shelvacu: Ok, now I can reproduce it. I need to be on non-Windows 64-bit.

Comment: I get the warning: "in a**b, b may be too big". There's probably some clue in https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1ea1d2e4a7911f5c43fdea2daadc2ea9201d4a4d/bignum.c

Comment: `Float::INFINITY > 10**309.1 #=> false` versus ` Float::INFINITY > 10**308.1 #=> true` on my Ubuntu 64 bits, Ruby 2.3.

Comment: @steenslag `Float::MAX # => 1.7976931348623157e+308`.

Comment: `10**9942066.0` is also infinity. It looks like in your first example, when the integer is too large, ruby automatically converts it to a floating point number, which cannot hold such a large number. See https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1ea1d2e4a7911f5c43fdea2daadc2ea9201d4a4d/bignum.c#L6342

Comment: @sawa Hmm, looks familiar indeed.

Comment: @xuhdev so why is 9942067 'too big'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**

I did the calculations done inside [numeric.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/numeric.c#L3500)'s `int_pow` manually, checking where an integer overflow (and a propagation to Bignum's, including a  call to `rb_big_pow`) occurs. Once the call to `rb_big_pow` happens there is a check whether the two intermediate values you've got in `int_pow` are too large or not, and the cutoff value seems to be just around 9942066 (if you're using a base of 10 for the power). Approximately this value is close to

```
BIGLEN_LIMIT / ceil(log2(base^n)) * n ==
32*1024*1024 / ceil(log2(10^16)) * 16 ==
32*1024*1024 / 54 * 16 ~=
9942054
```

where `BIGLEN_LIMIT` is an internal limit in ruby which is used as a constant to check if a power calculation would be too big or not, and is defined as `32*1024*1024`. `base` is 10, and `n` is the largest power-of-2 exponent for the base that would still fit inside a Fixnum.

Unfortunately I can't find a better way than this approximation, due to the algorithm used to calculate powers of big numbers, but it might be good enough to use as an upper limit if your code needs to check validity before doing exponentiation on big numbers.

---

**Original question:**

The problem is not with 9942066, but that with one of your number being an integer, the other one being a float. So

```
(10**9942066).class # => Bignum
(10**9942066.00000001).class # => Float
```

The first one is representable by a specific number internally, which is smaller than `Infinity`. The second one, as it's still a float is not representable by an actual number, and is simply replaced by `Infinity`, which is of course not larger than `Infinity`.

**Updated question:**

You are right that there seem to be some difference around 9942066 (if you're using a 64-bit ruby under Linux, as the limits might be different under other systems). While ruby does use the GMP library to handle big numbers, it does some precheck before even going to GMP, as shown by the warnings you can receive. It will also do the exponentiation manually using GMP's mul commands, without calling GMP's pow functions.

Fortunately the warnings are easy to catch:

```
irb(main):010:0> (10**9942066).class
=> Bignum

irb(main):005:0> (10**9942067).class
(irb):5: warning: in a**b, b may be too big
=> Float
```

And then you can actually check where these warnings are emitted inside ruby's [bignum.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_3/bignum.c#L6270) library.

But first we need to get to the Bignum realm, as both of our numbers are simple Fixnums. The initial part of the calculation, and the "upgrade" from fixnum to bignum is done inside [numeric.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/numeric.c#L3500). Ruby does quick exponentiation, and at every step it checks whether the result would still fit into a Fixnum (which is 2 bits less than the system bitsize: 62 bits on a 64 bit machine). If not, it will then convert the values to the Bignum realm, and continues the calculations there. We are interested at the point where this conversion happens, so let's try to figure out when it does in our `10^9942066` example (I'm using x,y,z variables as present inside the ruby's numeric.c code):

```
x = 10^1  z = 10^0   y = 9942066
x = 10^2  z = 10^0   y = 4971033
x = 10^2  z = 10^2   y = 4971032
x = 10^4  z = 10^2   y = 2485516
x = 10^8  z = 10^2   y = 1242758
x = 10^16 z = 10^2   y = 621379
x = 10^16 z = 10^18  y = 621378
x = OWFL
```

At this point x will overflow (`10^32 > 2^62-1`), so the process will continue on the Bignum realm by calculating `x**y`, which is `(10^16)^621378` (which are actually still both Fixnums at this stage)

If you now go back to [bignum.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_3/bignum.c#L6270) and check how it determines if a number is too large or not, you can see that it will check the number of bits required to hold `x`, and multiply this number with `y`. If the result is larger than `32*1024*1024`, it will then fail (emit a warning and does the calculations using basic floats).

`(10^16)` is 54 bits (`ceil(log_2(10^16)) == 54`), `54*621378` is 33554412. This is only slightly smaller than 33554432 (by 20), the limit after which ruby will not do Bignum exponentiation, but simply convert `y` to double, and hope for the best (which will obviously fail, and just return `Infinity`)

Now let's try to check this with 9942067:

```
x = 10^1   z = 10^0    y = 9942067
x = 10^1   z = 10^1    y = 9942066
x = 10^2   z = 10^1    y = 4971033
x = 10^2   z = 10^3    y = 4971032
x = 10^4   z = 10^3    y = 2485516
x = 10^8   z = 10^3    y = 1242758
x = 10^16  z = 10^3    y = 621379
x = 10^16  z = OWFL
```

Here, at the point z overflows (`10^19 > 2^62-1`), the calculation will continue on the Bignum realm, and will calculate `x**y`. Note that here it will calculate `(10^16)^621379`, and while `(10^16)` is still 54 bits, `54*621379` is 33554466, which is larger than 33554432 (by 34). As it's larger you'll get the warning, and ruby will only to calculations using double, hence the result is `Infinity`.

Note that these checks are only done if you are using the power function. That's why you can still do `(10**9942066)*10`, as similar checks are not present when doing plain multiplication, meaning you could implement your own quick exponentiation method in ruby, in which case it will still work with larger values, although you won't have this safety check anymore. See for example this quick implementation:

```
def unbounded_pow(x,n)
  if n < 0
    x = 1.0 / x
    n = -n
  end
  return 1 if n == 0
  y = 1
  while n > 1
    if n.even?
      x = x*x
      n = n/2
    else
      y = x*y
      x = x*x
      n = (n-1)/2
    end
  end
  x*y
end

puts (10**9942066) == (unbounded_pow(10,9942066)) # => true
puts (10**9942067) == (unbounded_pow(10,9942067)) # => false 
puts ((10**9942066)*10) == (unbounded_pow(10,9942067)) # => true
```

**But how would I know the cutoff for a specific base?**

My math is not exactly great, but I can tell a way to approximate where the cutoff value will be. If you check the above calls you can see the conversion between Fixnum and Bignum happens when the intermediate base reaches the limit of Fixnum. The intermediate base at this stage will always have an exponent which is a power of 2, so you just have to maximize this value. For example let's try to figure out the maximum cutoff value for 12.

First we have to check what is the highest base we can store in a Fixnum:

```
ceil(log2(12^1)) = 4
ceil(log2(12^2)) = 8
ceil(log2(12^4)) = 15
ceil(log2(12^8)) = 29
ceil(log2(12^16)) = 58
ceil(log2(12^32)) = 115
```

We can see `12^16` is the max we can store in 62 bits, or if we're using a 32 bit machine `12^8` will fit into 30 bits (ruby's Fixnums can store values up to two bits less than the machine size limit).

For `12^16` we can easily determine the cutoff value. It will be `32*1024*1024 / ceil(log2(12^16))`, which is `33554432 / 58 ~= 578525`. We can easily check this in ruby now:

```
irb(main):004:0> ((12**16)**578525).class
=> Bignum
irb(main):005:0> ((12**16)**578526).class
(irb):5: warning: in a**b, b may be too big
=> Float
```

Now we hate to go back to our original base of `12`. There the cutoff will be around `578525*16` (16 being the exponent of the new base), which is `9256400`. If you check in ruby, the values are actually quite close to this number:

```
irb(main):009:0> (12**9256401).class
=> Bignum
irb(main):010:0> (12**9256402).class
(irb):10: warning: in a**b, b may be too big
=> Float
```

Comment: But it also happens with 10^994206**7**, which also overflows to infinity. But why 9942066?

Comment: `10**9942066` isn't the maximum possible value, because `10**9942066 * 100` works just fine. (note: edited numbers)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your most recent edit. :/

Comment: "and the cutoff value seems to be just around 9942066 when the base is 10" but ***why??*** Is there some special overflow number that the result of 10**9942067 crosses that ..66 doesn't? How can I calculate where the overflow will be for other numbers without  doing a binary search?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the problem is not with the number but with the operation, as told by the warning you get.

```
$ ruby -e 'puts (1.0/0) > 10**9942067'
-e:1: warning: in a**b, b may be too big
false
```

The problem is `10**9942067` breaks Ruby's power function. Instead of throwing an exception, which would be a better behavior, it erroneously results in infinity.

```
$ ruby -e 'puts 10**9942067'
-e:1: warning: in a**b, b may be too big
Infinity
```

[The other answer explains why this happens near 10e9942067](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36631908/14660).

`10**9942067` is not greater than infinity, it is erroneously resulting in infinity. This is a bad habit of a lot of math libraries that makes mathematicians claw their eyeballs out in frustration.

Infinity is not greater than infinity, they're equal, so your greater than check is false. You can see this by checking if they're equal.

```
$ ruby -e 'puts (1.0/0) == 10**9942067'
-e:1: warning: in a**b, b may be too big
true
```

Contrast this with specifying the number directly using scientific notation. Now Ruby doesn't have to do math on huge numbers, it just knows that any real number is less than infinity.

```
$ ruby -e 'puts (1.0/0) > 10e9942067'
false
```

Now you can put on as big an exponent as you like.

```
$ ruby -e 'puts (1.0/0) > 10e994206700000000000000000000000000000000'
false
```